# two django server in one project

Tags: python, django

I am writing one project that has two servers, one is management node, one is the agent, all both are HTTP server.
Now should I just create two Django project for them? and only use one git repository. But I found there is some code common that all used by two projects. How to organize two projects is better?

Comment: First of all, I'm not sure if the question belongs to this forum. If you are concerned about security, it's a good idea to have two servers, one just working as a mediator, basically to restrict user interactions with the main server and modularise the system. But this comes with its own overhead. If u have decided to go with two servers, it's always better to have separate repositories for each.

Comment: if separate repositories for each, how to handle the situation that two project have some common used files

Comment: If you have some modules that are constantly used, It's better to combine all of them and put it in a 3rd separate repository, making it a library, called from other modules. Usually, it is called utilities. But I'm not sure if this is the perfect thing for you since I'm you have not given many details.

Comment: if I use one common directory, can I just use "sys.path.append(<path to common_dir>)" to realize it.

Comment: why not just one git repositories, I think it's more better :)